# Django Forms Not Setting Initial Values

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to use `def clean(self)` to raise Validation Errors if necessary. However before I can use it all my fields have to be populated. THus I set inital values in my views.py like so:

```
offering = DirectOffering.objects.get(id=offering_id)
current_user = InvestorProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)

form = DirectInvestmentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'offering': offering, 'user': current_user})

form.fields['user'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()    
form.fields['offering'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()    

if form.is_valid():
    investment = form.save(commit=False)

    investment.save()
```

However when I look at Local Vars on my error page I see:

`cleaned_data {'offering': None, 'quantity': 12345678, 'user': None}`

Quantity is what i entered the other two fields should have been autopopulated by initial={}

Comment: yes because the offering_id and request.user is blank and the query is not returning anything, you need to pass offering_id and request.user.pk

Comment: Changed to `form = DirectInvestmentForm(request.POST or None, initial={'offering': offering_id, 'user': request.user.pk})` but still same error.

Comment: post your total view and also the html

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/z11mWLtx) is the entire view, and [here](https://pastebin.com/hADpWzAC) is my HTML.